# Sorting algorithm, (quick sort) small bug

Tags: c++, sorting

So, this is my sorting algorithm. the output is:

```
0,2,3,3,2,1,4,6,10,12,12,5,15,21,21,15,22,32,26,29,...
```

It is close but there is a bug in it somewhere I can't seem to find.  Every 6th number is wrong.

My vector length is 20000.  So I call the function

```
quickSort(a,0,20000); //(I think it is support to be 0,20000, but I am not sure though..)
```

I think this is correct, not sure though.

```
template <typename Comparable>
const Comparable& median3(vector<Comparable>& a, int left, int right){
    int center=(left+right)/2;
    if(a[center]<a[left]){
        swap(a[center],a[left]);
    }
    if(a[right]<a[left]){
        swap(a[right],a[left]);
    }
    if(a[right]<a[center]){
        swap(a[right],a[center]);
    }
    swap(a[center],a[right-1]);
    return a[right-1];
}


template <typename Comparable>
void quickSort(vector<Comparable>& a, int left = 0, int right = 20000){

    if(left+10 <= right){
        const Comparable& pivot = median3(a,left,right);
        int i=left;
        int j=right-1;
        for(;;){
            while(a[++i] < pivot){}
            while(pivot < a[--j]){}
            if(i<j){
                swap(a[i],a[j]);
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
        swap(a[i], a[right-1]);
        quickSort(a,left,i-1);
        quickSort(a,i+1,right);
    }
    else{
    //
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you [reinventing the wheel](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/)? Also : `for(;;)` will produce a deadlock at some point _(In fact it **is** a deadlock)_. **Never** use boundless loops, even static code analysis tools will cry about that

Comment: I'm creating a bunch of sort algorithms.. how would you recommend fixing the boundless loop?

Comment: simply use `while(someStaticVolatileBooleanHere)` ... thats basic programming. Your "bunch of sort algorithms" quite likely already exist in the stdlib.

Comment: It's for a class.. my other sorts worked fine but this one is a no go ;s

Comment: Yes ... stop reinventing the wheel. A programmer who does that will never succeed. Programming and software development is **all about** re-using well-tested, standardized libraries in clever ways and learning from them.

Comment: The best way to debug recursive logic is start small. Sort a list of 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 then 5 then 6 in a debugger. It will quickly become clear where it goes an unexpected way.

Comment: @specializt Tell that the teacher. It seems that this is an exercise...

Comment: @specializt But re-inventing the wheel is a great way of learning to program, and learning algorithms. OTOH running to SO at the first sign of trouble...

Comment: Feel free to tell him that such an exercise is purely mathematical and quite senseless, you guys should learn about OOP and whatnot ... just sayan

Comment: @specializt every other class i take is OOP.. learning how to write algorithms is pretty important imo..

Comment: @juanchopanza no, in fact that may just the the worst imaginable way of learning to program. **At first** the student needs to understand basic programming logic - by looking at examples and by being told what they do. **Then** he does a few assisted exercises aaaand onto the next lesson

Comment: I partly agree. It depends on how or where you learn to program. In universities with theoretical background you very likely learn to write basic algorithms (= reinventing wheels) before (or after) learning how to use them. In an application-oriented course this might not be the case as it is considered unnecessary. I personally don't like such people because they tend to not really understand what they use all day. I fully agree however that although students should have learned it once, the focus shouldn't be on how to write core stuff but how to use it to create high level stuff with it.

Comment: @BrianJ This is not about "writing algorithms", its about solving mathematical problems

Comment: @leemes In that case you either met only incompetent people _(which is somewhat likely)_ or you never met actual software developers. Using a tool without knowing how it works is nigh-impossible ... at least if you're trying to use it inside of environments with great requirements for software quality

Comment: @specializt I didn't say they should start with algorithms. You seem to be claiming they should never implement algorithms that have already been implemented. But I guess you're the programming education expert, so I leave you the stage.

Comment: This is similar to the question why people need math skills these days, as we have computers solving that for us. It is still important to understand the problem and to know (at least vague) how to solve it, even if you have the tools solving it for you and if your job doesn't really *require* you to solve them by hand. This is at least my opinion about truly skilled people.

Comment: Well, this is a rant, partly interesting, but not belonging here.

Comment: Feel free to write, debug and learn but do not use.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if(left+10 <= right){
```

Makes no sense to me. Essentially your routine doesn't bother to sort sub-lists of lest than 10 elements.

Why? It's a recursive algorithm and needs to sort down to lists of 2 items to finish properly.

As I said in my comment test your recursive algorithm from small to large sizes.
The error will pop out very quickly.

Comment: @BrianJ You wrote it but "didn't quiet [sic] understand it"? Are you improvising or something? (It looks a lot like you copied the code from somewhere and commented out the part that doesn't quicksort recursively, but I prefer to not believe that.)

Comment: @BrianJ Looking at Wikipedia it looks like you're trying to implement the Hoare partition scheme with Sedgewicks pivot strategy. No problem with that. But go and look carefully at the pseudo code there and just try translating it into C++.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I'll take a look at it.   @molbdnilo  I mean, yeah, I thought that was pretty obvious. It was some pseudo code from class I was implementing to an actual c++ algo.